# Is it possible to parallelise asp.net pre-compilation

Tags: asp.net, compilation, parallel-processing

I know MSBuild supports parallelisation, but it seems aspnet_compiler does not.  Are there any third party tools that do?

Comment: what do you want to get? Are you using .NET 4 and IIS 7? There are certain other techniques in this case...